# Assert a type is not branded

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

If we define a type brand such as:

```
declare const nominalSymbol: unique symbol;
type Nominal<T extends string, U> = U & { [nominalSymbol]: T };
```

Is there a way to define a type `NotNominal<U>` which resolves to `U` if `U` is not a branded type.

```
declare const nominalSymbol: unique symbol;
type Nominal<T extends string, U> = U & { [nominalSymbol]: T };

type BrandedType = Nominal<'Address', string>;

type a = NotNominal<string> // this should be `string`
type b = NotNominal<Address> // this should be `never`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type NotNominal<U> = U extends { [nominalSymbol]: string } ? never : U
```

Comment: Please add some text that explains your answer.